# C# : Server error on deployment of Crystal Reports

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to deploy my webapp which includes `crystal reports and charts` but

I am getting this error message

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine,
 Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'
 or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

Line 70:         <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
Line 71:         <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
Line 72:        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
Line 73:        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
Line 74:        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
```

`Source File: D:\testl\web.config    Line: 72`

Do I need to install something to get this work?

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding Crystal Reports Runtime on the Web Server.

You can find some of them here, mainly the ones for Runtime 2008:
http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp

Comment: I am hosting my app on goDaddy so do i need to ask goDaddy to install this or manually install this runtime and attach to my project?

Comment: I believe they need to... even if you include the Crystal assemblies referenced in your project with your deployed app it will not work because those reference some COM dlls that the runtime installs.

Comment: FYI Runtime link is messed up on current SAP site, here's the correct direct link for 13.0.5 64-bit runtime: http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crnetruntime/clickonce/CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_5.msi